# Como saber se o form recebido no php é um insert, delete ou update?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer um sistema CRUD com html e PHP, na qual o PHP toma determinada medida de acordo com o tipo de solicitação (se é cadastro, atualização ou exclusao)
mas nao sei como passar isso do html para o PHP.

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="nome" name="nome" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nome: ">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email: ">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date" name="nascimento" class="form-control" placeholder="Data de nascimento: ">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha:">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" name='cadastro' class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

// 'cadastro' refere-se ao name do submit, mas nao funcionou
    if($_POST['cadastro']) { 

        $banco = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'crud');

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];
        $nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES ('', '$nome' , '$email' , '$senha', '$nascimento')";

        echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";

        mysqli_query($banco, $sql);
        mysqli_close($banco);

        echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `eu preciso saber reconhecer oq o usuario quer, se é inserir algo, remover algo ou alterar algo`... Esqueceu do mais importante, que é o usuário tentando encontrar falhas. Sempre vai ter alguem pra alterar o 'attr name' do seu button pra editar/deletar algo que não existe ou não pertence a ele.

Answer (score 0):

Cara boa noite, vc está indo na caminho certo, 
porem,
primeiramente vc deve criar mais dois submit um para editar e outro para cadastrar  e colocar mais duas condições para executar a ação chamada.

vc não está conseguindo inserir nada pq, vc não passou os campos do seu banco da tabela usuario e tem um '' antes de $nome, a forma correta seria essa(mas substitua conforme o nome da sua tabela no banco) :

`$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(nome, email,senha,nascimento) VALUES ('$nome' , '$email' , '$senha', '$nascimento')";`

Comment: Boa noite! O insert ja esta funcionando, porem eu nao sei como reconhecer no php quando é um insert ou um update, pois cada tipo é uma função diferente. Tentei fazer algo como " if(cadastro) {} mas nao funcionou

Comment: bom isso não é php é SQL.

Comment: eu preciso saber reconhecer oq o usuario quer, se é inserir algo, remover algo ou alterar algo, o restante ja esta pronto

Comment: vc deve criar mais dois submit(butão) um para editar e outro para cadastrar no html dentro da tag form e colocar mais duas condições(IF ) para executar a ação chamada.

Comment: @ViniciusHenriqueCamposDeAr dê uma olhada nesse artigo [link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/12/php-and-mysql-crud-tutorial.html), ensina passo a passo a criar, ler, editar e deletar, nesse artigo e usado **PDO**, pois `mysqli` foi descontinuado.